# Sql query replicates certain field

Tags: mysql, sql

Following is my sql query:

```
select given_name,value_numeric,name from 
(select given_name from person_name where person_id IN
(select patient_id from patient_identifier where identifier='BED203016'))
as alias,

(select value_numeric from obs where concept_id IN
(select concept_id from concept_name where name='MediObsForm_Quantity' and concept_name_type='FULLY_SPECIFIED' and locale='en')
 and person_id=86)
 as alias2,

 (select name from concept_name where concept_id IN
 (select value_coded from obs where concept_id IN
 (select concept_id from concept_name where name='MediObsForm_Drug_Name' and concept_name_type='FULLY_SPECIFIED' and locale='en')
 and person_id=86) 
 and locale='en')
 as alias3;
```

This gives me the output as:

```
given_name  value_numeric  name
Amit             18        Med1
Amit             28        Med1  
Amit             18        Med2  
Amit             28        Med2
```

This is not the output I expected.I was expecting the following output:

```
given_name  value_numeric  name  
Amit             18        Med1  
Amit             28        Med2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EWCo.jpg

In the obs table,the person_id refers to the particular user.Here 86 refers to 'Amit'.
In the same table concept_id=3769 refers to MediObsForm_Drug_Name in concept_name table.
In obs table concept_id 3769 has a value which is defined by column 'K' in the picture.
So it has a value as concept_id=3768.So in concept_name table concept_id=3768 has a name Almox dt... which is Med1

Similarly concept_id=3791 in obs refers to MedObsForm_Quantity in the concept_name table.In the obs table,column 'O' refers to the value_numeric which is the quantity.In the pic its 28 and 18.

Comment: Ok, but how you know that `obs.O` with value 18 corresponds to `Med1` in `concept_name`?

Comment: In the obs table,column H,obs_group_id binds them.The name of the medicine and the quantity have the same obs_group_id.So quantity 28 belongs to concept_id=3768.Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Perhaps a DISTINCT can help in the first line

Comment: Got the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select cn2.name as Medicine_Name,o.obs_group_id,o.person_id, data.Qty from obs o
inner join concept_name cn2 on o.value_coded=cn2.concept_id and o.concept_id=3769
and cn2.concept_name_type='FULLY_SPECIFIED' and cn2.locale ='en'

inner join (select o.value_numeric as Qty,o.obs_group_id from obs o
inner join concept_name cn2 on o.concept_id=cn2.concept_id and o.concept_id=3791
and cn2.concept_name_type='FULLY_SPECIFIED' and cn2.locale ='en'
) data on data.obs_group_id =o.obs_group_id;
```

This is the solution.